# Any reason why odoo database is getting created without tables?

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

`python3 odoo-bin -i base -d mydb --limit-memory-hard 0`

After running the above command, not sure why the database `mydb` is getting created empty, no relations inside the db.

```
2022-10-12 07:24:27,456 53139 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 15.0 
2022-10-12 07:24:27,456 53139 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at /Users/u/.odoorc 
2022-10-12 07:24:27,456 53139 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/Users/u/odoo/odoo/addons', '/Users/u/Library/Application Support/Odoo/addons/15.0', '/Users/u/odoo/addons'] 
2022-10-12 07:24:27,456 53139 INFO ? odoo: database: default@default:default 
2022-10-12 07:24:27,584 53139 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: You need Wkhtmltopdf to print a pdf version of the reports. 
2022-10-12 07:24:27,614 53139 CRITICAL ? odoo.modules.module: Couldn't load module base 
2022-10-12 07:24:27,614 53139 CRITICAL ? odoo.modules.module: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK' 
2022-10-12 07:24:27,614 53139 ERROR ? odoo.service.server: Failed to load server-wide module `base`. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 1210, in load_server_wide_modules
    odoo.modules.module.load_openerp_module(m)
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/modules/module.py", line 396, in load_openerp_module
    __import__('odoo.addons.' + module_name)
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/addons/base/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import models
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import ir_mail_server
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_mail_server.py", line 19, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto as SSLCrypto
  File "/Users/u/odoo/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/Users/u/odoo/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1553, in <module>
    class X509StoreFlags(object):
  File "/Users/u/odoo/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1573, in X509StoreFlags
    CB_ISSUER_CHECK = _lib.X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'
2022-10-12 07:24:27,618 53139 CRITICAL ? odoo.modules.module: Couldn't load module web 
2022-10-12 07:24:27,618 53139 CRITICAL ? odoo.modules.module: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK' 
2022-10-12 07:24:27,618 53139 ERROR ? odoo.service.server: Failed to load server-wide module `web`.
The `web` module is provided by the addons found in the `openerp-web` project.
Maybe you forgot to add those addons in your addons_path configuration. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 1210, in load_server_wide_modules
    odoo.modules.module.load_openerp_module(m)
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/modules/module.py", line 396, in load_openerp_module
    __import__('odoo.addons.' + module_name)
  File "/Users/u/odoo/addons/web/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import controllers
  File "/Users/u/odoo/addons/web/controllers/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import main
  File "/Users/u/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 34, in <module>
    from odoo.addons.base.models.ir_qweb import render as qweb_render
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/addons/base/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import models
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import ir_mail_server
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_mail_server.py", line 19, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto as SSLCrypto
  File "/Users/u/odoo/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/Users/u/odoo/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1553, in <module>
    class X509StoreFlags(object):
  File "/Users/u/odoo/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1573, in X509StoreFlags
    CB_ISSUER_CHECK = _lib.X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'
2022-10-12 07:24:27,630 53139 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa:8069 
2022-10-12 07:24:27,663 53139 INFO ? odoo.modules.loading: init db 
2022-10-12 07:24:27,910 53139 INFO mydb odoo.modules.loading: loading 1 modules... 
2022-10-12 07:24:27,910 53139 INFO mydb odoo.modules.loading: Loading module base (1/1) 
2022-10-12 07:24:27,911 53139 CRITICAL mydb odoo.modules.module: Couldn't load module base 
2022-10-12 07:24:27,911 53139 CRITICAL mydb odoo.modules.module: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK' 
2022-10-12 07:24:27,917 53139 ERROR mydb odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE ir_module_module SET state='installed' WHERE state IN ('to remove', 'to upgrade')
ERROR: relation "ir_module_module" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE ir_module_module SET state='installed' WHERE state IN...
               ^
 
2022-10-12 07:24:27,917 53139 ERROR mydb odoo.modules.registry: Failed to load registry 
2022-10-12 07:24:27,917 53139 CRITICAL mydb odoo.service.server: Failed to initialize database `mydb`. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 87, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 415, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, processed_modules = load_module_graph(
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 179, in load_module_graph
    load_openerp_module(package.name)
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/modules/module.py", line 396, in load_openerp_module
    __import__('odoo.addons.' + module_name)
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/addons/base/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import models
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import ir_mail_server
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_mail_server.py", line 19, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto as SSLCrypto
  File "/Users/u/odoo/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/Users/u/odoo/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1553, in <module>
    class X509StoreFlags(object):
  File "/Users/u/odoo/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1573, in X509StoreFlags
    CB_ISSUER_CHECK = _lib.X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 1260, in preload_registries
    registry = Registry.new(dbname, update_module=update_module)
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 89, in new
    odoo.modules.reset_modules_state(db_name)
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 599, in reset_modules_state
    cr.execute(
  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in execute
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 90, in check
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/u/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 313, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "ir_module_module" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE ir_module_module SET state='installed' WHERE state IN...
               ^
```

The odoo was running fine initially. Not sure what happened.

Comment: What is the purpose of using "--limit-memory-hard 0"

Comment: It keeps complaining about some module not having some attribute. If code did not change then I'm tempted to say the library it keeps referring to (lib) was updated and deprecated said flag?

Comment: Updated pyopenssl to 22.0.0 to [fix the issue](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/99809#issuecomment-1240553258)

Comment: Yeah, pyopenssl update worked. Thank you.